# ‘myClock’ was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++

The error is occurring in the implementation file. I am trying to use the myClock object with the difference function and pass yourClock within it allowing me to subtract both of those times elapsed from each other and find the difference between them.

Similar to how the equalTime function works using myClock with yourClock as the parameter and copying the times. Except to subject those times after they've been elapsed from the timeElapsed function then print the difference.

I continue getting this error and I am not understanding where it is I have to declare myClock. I apologize if it is simple. I am currently in college completing these assignment and trying to learn from the mistakes. Below is also the exact error.

```
clockTypeImp.cpp: In member function ‘void clockType::difference(clockType&)’:
clockTypeImp.cpp:43:13: error: ‘myClock’ was not declared in this scope
     diff = (myClock.elapsedTime() - o
             ^
bash: line 2: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

clockType.h

```
class clockType
    {
    public: 
        void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
        void setHours(int hours);
        void setMinutes(int minutes);
        void setSeconds(int seconds);
        long elapsedTime();
    long remainingTime();
    void difference(clockType& otherClock);

    void getTime(int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds) const;

    int getHours() const
    {
        return hr;
    }

    int getMinutes() const
    {
        return min;
    }
    int getSeconds() const
    {
        return sec;
    }

    void printTime() const;

    void incrementSeconds();

    void incrementMinutes();

    void incrementHours();

    bool equalTime(const clockType& otherClock) const;

    clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);

    clockType();

private:
    int hr;  //variable to store the hours
    int min; //variable to store the minutes
    int sec; //variable to store the seconds
};
```

clockTypeImp.cpp

```
//Implementation File for the class clockType

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "clockType.h"

using namespace std; 

void clockType::setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
        hr = hours;
    else 
        hr = 0;

    if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)
        min = minutes;
    else 
        min = 0;

    if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)
        sec = seconds;
    else 
        sec = 0;
}

long clockType::elapsedTime()
{
    return (hr * 3600 + min * 60 + sec);
}

long clockType::remainingTime()
{
    return ((24 * 3600) - (hr * 3600 + min * 60 + sec));
}

void clockType::difference(clockType& otherClock)
{

    long diff;
    int hrs, mins, secs;

    diff = (myClock.elapsedTime() - otherClock.elapsedTime());

    if (diff > 0){
        hrs = (diff / 3600);
        mins = (diff - hrs * 3600) / 60;
        secs = (diff - (hrs * 3600 + mins * 60));

        cout << "The Clock 2 is far apart from clock 1 by: ";
        if (hrs < 10)
            cout << "0";
            cout << hrs << ":";

        if (mins < 10)
            cout << "0";
            cout << mins << ":";

        if (secs < 10)
            cout << "0";
            cout << secs << endl; 
    }

    else if (diff < 0)
    {
        diff = (otherClock.elapsedTime() - myClock.elapsedTime());
        hrs = (diff / 3600);
        mins = (diff - hrs * 3600) / 60;
        secs = (diff - (hrs * 3600 + mins * 60));

        cout << "The Clock 1 is far apart from clock 2 by: ";
        if (hrs < 10)
            cout << "0";
            cout << hrs << ":";

        if (mins < 10)
            cout << "0";
            cout << mins << ":";

        if (secs < 10)
            cout << "0";
            cout << secs << endl; 
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "Both the clocks have the same time " << "The difference is 00:00:00" << endl;
    }

}

void clockType::setHours(int hours)
{
    if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
        hr = hours;
    else 
        hr = 0;
}

void clockType::setMinutes(int minutes)
{
    if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)
        min = minutes;
    else 
        min = 0;
}

void clockType::setSeconds(int seconds)
{
    if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)
        sec = seconds;
    else 
        sec = 0;
}

void clockType::getTime(int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds) const
{
    hours = hr;
    minutes = min;
    seconds = sec;
}

void clockType::incrementHours()
{
    hr++;
    if(hr > 23)
       hr = 0;
}

void clockType::incrementMinutes()
{
    min++;
    if (min > 59)
    {
        min = 0;
        incrementHours();
    }
}

void clockType::incrementSeconds()
{
    sec++;

    if (sec > 59)
    {
        sec = 0;
        incrementMinutes();
    }
}

void clockType::printTime() const
{
    if (hr < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << hr << ":";

    if (min < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << min << ":";

    if (sec < 10)
       cout << "0";
    cout << sec;
}

bool clockType::equalTime(const clockType& otherClock) const
{
    return (hr == otherClock.hr 
            && min == otherClock.min 
            && sec == otherClock.sec);
}

clockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
        hr = hours;
    else 
        hr = 0;

    if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)
        min = minutes;
    else 
        min = 0;

    if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)
        sec = seconds;
    else 
        sec = 0;
}

clockType::clockType()  //default constructor
{
    hr = 0;
    min = 0;
    sec = 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
//The user program that uses the class clockType

#include <iostream> 
#include "clockType.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    clockType myClock;
    clockType yourClock;   

    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    myClock.setTime(5, 4, 30); 

    cout << "myClock: "; 
    myClock.printTime();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "yourClock: "; 
    yourClock.printTime();
    cout << endl; 

        //Set the time of yourClock
    yourClock.setTime(5, 45, 16); 

    cout << "After setting, yourClock: ";
    yourClock.printTime();
    cout << endl; 

    cout << "Enter the hours, minutes, and "
         << "seconds: ";  
    cin >> hours >> minutes >> seconds; 
    cout << endl; 

    myClock.setHours(hours);
    myClock.setMinutes(minutes);
    myClock.setSeconds(seconds);

    cout << "myClock: "; 
    myClock.printTime(); 
    cout << endl;  

    myClock.incrementSeconds(); 

    cout << "After incrementing myClock by " 
         << "one second, myClock: "; 
    myClock.printTime(); 
    cout << endl; 

        //Output the value of hours, minutes, and seconds
        //of myClock
    cout << "hours = " << myClock.getHours() 
         << ", minutes = " << myClock.getMinutes() 
         << ", seconds = " << myClock.getSeconds() << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << "The elapsed time of the day is: " <<
        myClock.elapsedTime() << " seconds" << endl;

    cout << "The remaining time of the day is: " << myClock.remainingTime() << " seconds" << endl;

myClock.difference(yourClock);

    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: You define the variable `myClock` in the `main` function. It is not passed on to the `difference` function. Therefore the `difference` function doesn't know anything about a variable or symbol `myClock`.

Comment: In `diff = (myClock.elapsedTime() - otherClock.elapsedTime())` with `myClock` you most likely mean the object you are currently in? So just write `elapsedTime()` or `this->elapsedTime()`.

Comment: Change `myClock.elapsedTime()` to `this->elapsedTime()`. The reason why to do this is explained by other people above.

Comment: You did this correctly, without depending on a particular variable name, with the "increment" functions, so I guess you just didn't think of a generalisation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to get the difference from current clock with  respect to the passed clock, what you can do is to replace `diff = (myClock.elapsedTime() - otherClock.elapsedTime());` with `diff = (elapsedTime() - otherClock.elapsedTime())`

What happens is, even though you declare myClock in the main, it never gets passed to the function `difference()`. In the suggestion I gave what it does is, the difference function will invoke it's `elapsedTime()` function(with respect to the myClock object) and then compare it with the passed ClockType object.

Comment: ahh something so simple and minor. I appreciate it a lot and I completely understand it. I just never caught it because I was trying so hard to get the elapsed time of specifically of myClock in there. With the increments it was different in my mind because I wasn't trying to do an equation between both times after they had already passed through the other functions. I did do this for equalTime but for whatever reason I sat and stared at and couldn't figure it out for the life of me.